# Ckick make a td of a table to which I make the content code

Tags: jquery, html

I need to know how I can click on the td table or button as appropriate for the object and do more things with , this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#DTablas").draggable();
$("#btctable").click(function(){
   creatabla(4,6);
});
function creatabla(to,tn){
    var i=0,j=0,headers="",bodyes="",hid="",bid="";
    while(j<=tn){
        if(j===0){
            for(i;i<=to;i++){
                /*se hara la linea de los headres*/
                if(i===0){
                    headers="<thead><tr>" + "<th id='h" + i + "'>" + "<button type='button' id='bttH" + i + "'>" + "H" + i + "</button></th>";
                }else if(i===to){
                    headers=headers + "</tr></thead>";
                }else{
                    headers=headers + "<th id='h" + i + "'>" + "<button type='button' id='bttH" + i + "'>" + "H" + i + "</button></th>";
                }
            }
            i=0;
            j++;
            bodyes="<tbody>";    
        }else{
            for(i;i<=to;i++){
                if(i===0){
                    bodyes=bodyes + "<tr><td id='" + "bd" + i + "'>" + "BD" + i + "</td>";
                }else if(i===to){
                    bodyes=bodyes + "</tr>";
                }else{
                    bodyes=bodyes + "<td id='" + "bd" + i + "'>" + "BD" + i + "</td>";
                }
            }
            j++;
            i=0;
        }
    }
    bodyes=bodyes + "</tbody>";
    /*parte de al final*/
    $("#tresps").append(headers);
    $("#tresps").append(bodyes);
}
$("td[id^='btth']").click(function(evt){
    var tar=evt.target;
    alert("el id del botón es: " + tar.id);
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

});
It does not work with or without the button

I need to click the < td > button or < td > , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be adding dynamic content to the DOM which you also want to catch the events on.
With `$(selector).click(//...` you only add a handler to all already **existing** elements. When you want to listen to all events matching your selector even when the elements have been added after you registered the event you have to do it like this:

```
$(selector).click(function(...) { ... });
// becomes
$(selector).on("click", function(...) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks really your answer solved my problem and contributed to more application ideas, your explanation took me questions and I could continue thanks greetings

Comment: @CapoBugbler Don't forget to upvote the answer ;) I'm happy I could help you.